# Priority-Web-SDK: getRows has limit of 100 results

Tags: javascript, erp, priority-web-sdk

I am trying to get more than 101 rows from a Subform, for doing that, I am open the parent form and search for some value (by building a filter, using setSearchFilter and getRows(1)), right after I got the needed rows in the parent form, I opened SubForm (startSubForm), and with the instance of the subForms I called to getRows(1), getRows(1) return 101 results (rows) instead of 600 results.
How can I retrieve more than 101 results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation of retrieving up to 100 rows from priority when invoking getRows method. However, you can retrieve the rows in bulks by passing the fromRow param.

The definition of getRows according to the [API](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) is as followed:

```
getRows( fromRow, [onSuccess] , [onError] ) ⇒ Promise
```

When you invoke getRows(1) you will receive the first 100 rows.
You can get the second bulk by passing getRows(101) and so on.

A different option to get all the rows in one go is using REST API which has no limitation on the quantity of returned rows.